# Converting any negative values in pd.dataframe to positive, but the positive values become NaN

Tags: python, pandas, nan, boolean-logic

I have a pd.dataframe as shown below. For any negative values, i want to add 256 to make it positive.  My code works for this part, however the other 2 positive values become NaN and I do not want that.  How can I only 256 to negative value and leave the positive numbers unchanged? Many thanks

my pandas dataframe dfx:

```
red green  blue
```

0   72  101    -125

'''

dfx = dfx[dfx < 0] + 256

current output:

```
red green   blue
```

0   NaN NaN 131

desired output:

```
red green  blue
```

0   72  101    131

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html):

```
dfx = dfx.mask(dfx < 0, dfx + 256 )
print (dfx)
   red  green  blue
0   72    101   131
```

Your solution should be changed:

```
dfx[dfx < 0] += 256
print (dfx)
   red  green  blue
0   72    101   131
```